# Summary result of two query multiples columns

Tags: mysql, sql, union-all

I have this table:

teams:

```
--------------
id....teamname....id_league
----------------------------
1.....team1...........2
----------------------------
2.....team2...........2
----------------------------
3.....team3...........2
----------------------------
4.....team4...........2
----------------------------
```

and this table:
results:

```
----------------------------------------------------
id.....id_home.....id_away.....res_home.....res_away
----------------------------------------------------
1..........1..........2..........0.............4
----------------------------------------------------
2..........3..........4..........1.............2
----------------------------------------------------
3..........3..........2..........3.............4
----------------------------------------------------
4..........4..........1..........1.............2
----------------------------------------------------
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    teams.id,
    teams.teamname,
    SUM(res_home) AS r1,
    SUM(res_away) AS r2
FROM
    results
    INNER JOIN teams ON results.id_home = teams.id
WHERE
    teams.id_league = 2
GROUP BY
    teams.id
```

Result is:

```
--------------------------------------------
teamid...teamname........r1...............r2
--------------------------------------------
1.........team1...........0................4
--------------------------------------------
2.........team2...........0................0
--------------------------------------------
3.........team3...........4................6
--------------------------------------------
4.........team4...........1................2
--------------------------------------------
```

And I have this query:

```
SELECT
    teams.id,
    teams.teamname,
    SUM(res_away) AS r1,
    SUM(res_home) AS r2
FROM
    results
    INNER JOIN teams ON results.id_away = teams.id
WHERE
    teams.id_league = 2
GROUP BY
    teams.id
```

Result is:

```
--------------------------------------------
teamid...teamname........r1...............r2
--------------------------------------------
1.........team1...........2................1
--------------------------------------------
2.........team2...........4................0
--------------------------------------------
3.........team3...........0................0
--------------------------------------------
4.........team4...........2................1
--------------------------------------------
```

**Now I would like to get the union of both**. I want this result:

```
--------------------------------------------
teamid...teamname........r1...............r2
--------------------------------------------
1.........team1...........2................5
--------------------------------------------
2.........team2...........4................0
--------------------------------------------
3.........team3...........4................6
--------------------------------------------
4.........team4...........3................3
--------------------------------------------
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to unpivot before joining:

```
SELECT t.id, t.teamname, SUM(res) AS r1, SUM(opponent) AS r2
FROM teams t JOIN
     ((SELECT r.id_home as team_id, res_home as res, res_away as opponent
       FROM results r
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT r.id_away as team_id, res_away as res, res_home as opponent
       FROM results r
      )
     ) r
     ON r.team_id = t.id 
WHERE t.id_league = 2
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: I can't test it. Phpmyadmin said that your query has a syntax error..

Comment: I just remove this part " ts.id_home = teams.id" on line 10 and works for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

another way is two merge two join conditions:

```
SELECT
    teams.id,
    teams.teamname,
    SUM(case results.id_home when teams.id then res_home else res_away end) AS r1,
    SUM(case results.id_home when teams.id then res_away else res_home end) AS r2
FROM
    results
    INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id IN (results.id_away,results.id_home)
WHERE
    teams.id_league = 2
GROUP BY
    teams.id
    , teams.teamname
```